# How to reformat JSON response using values from Array

Tags: php, json, pdo

Essentially I have the following script with the following response:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('

    SELECT
        `tablelist`.`id`,
        `tablelist`.`content`
        FROM `tablelist `
    ');
    
    $stmt->execute([
      
      ]);
      
  $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $rowcount = $stmt->rowCount();
    
     
    if ($rowcount < 1) {
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }else{

        echo json_encode($row);
        
        
    }

?>
```

**Current Response:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "content": "Reason 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "content": "Reason 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "content": "Reason 3"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "content": "Reason 4"
  }
]
```

**I would instead like to present this array as the following (no square brackets):**

```
{
  "error": false,
  "content": {
    "1": "Reason 1",
    "2": "Reason 2",
    "3": "Reason 3",
    "4": "Reason 4"
}
```

**I know I need to do the following:**

```
$response["error"] = FALSE;
$response["content"][$row[id]] = $row[content];
```

But using this method I am not getting any values from the array.

How can present the values from the array the way?

Comment: What does that mean, “I am not getting any values from the array”? What *do* you get?

Comment: I get null because the array values are not being formatted into $response[“content”][$row[id]] = $row[content]

Comment: The question is not about JSON but about simple array processing.

Answer (score 2):

Look at `array_column` function and Example #2 at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

You can transform your rows like this but you must be aware of the uniqueness

```php
$content = '[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "content": "Reason 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "content": "Reason 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "content": "Reason 3"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "content": "Reason 4"
  }
]';

$from = json_decode($content, true);
$to = json_encode(array_column($from, 'content', 'id'), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo $to;
```

will result to

```json
{
    "1": "Reason 1",
    "2": "Reason 2",
    "3": "Reason 3",
    "4": "Reason 4"
}
```

via https://3v4l.org/WL29a

Comment: Instead of writing out the content I would just use json_encode($row) right? Otherwise I am hardcoding and I can’t do that.

Comment: no, you should do `$response['error'] = false; $response['content'] = array_column($row, 'content', 'id'); echo json_encode($response);` inside your `else` block

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very easily with PDO using the `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` fetch mode. It will use the first column from SQL as a key and the second as the value.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT
        `tablelist`.`id`,
        `tablelist`.`content`
        FROM `tablelist `
');

$stmt->execute(); 

$dataFromDB = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);

if (!$dataFromDB) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => true]);
} else {
    echo json_encode(['error' => false, 'content' => $dataFromDB]);
}
```

This will produce an output similar to this if there were any rows returned from the SELECT:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "content": {
        "1": "Reason 1",
        "2": "Reason 2",
        "3": "Reason 3",
        "4": "Reason 4"
    }
}
```